# How to use an external instance of ActiveMQ with OpenEJB?

Tags: jms, ejb, activemq-classic, openejb

how can I configure OpenEJB to work with an external instance of ActiveMQ?

We already tried the configuration on this link http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html but it did'nt work at all.

What should we do?

Comment: if this is still not working, can you post your openejb.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Try following in your `openejb.xml`:

```
<openejb>
    <Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        ServerUrl tcp://someHostName:61616
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="MyJmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        ResourceAdapter MyJmsResourceAdapter
    </Resource>

    <Container id="MyJmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">
        ResourceAdapter MyJmsResourceAdapter
    </Container>

    <Resource id="FooQueue" type="javax.jms.Queue"/>
    <Resource id="BarTopic" type="javax.jms.Topic"/>
</openejb>
```

Taken from [this doc](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html)

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade OpenEJB to use ActiveMQ 5.4? Internally or externally...

Comment: The coming 3.1.3 binaries support ActiveMQ 5.x.  It will ship with 5.3.1, but should be easy to yank those out and add 5.4.  Maybe we can sneak out a 3.1.4 with ActiveMQ 5.4.1.

Comment: @Kico: I've had the same experience with this setup.  If you don't get a connection refused exception when OpenEJB starts, then things are hooked up correctly.  My mistake in doing similar was that the topic/queue names did not line-up.  ActiveMQ will happily create any topic/queue you ask for and never gives a "no such topic" type of exception.  Nor does it log the topics and queues it does create.  Fortunately ActiveMQ has good JMX support and I was able to use jconsole to browse around the broker and see what topics/queues existed and how many messages they had.  Give that a try.

Comment: @DavidBlevins - I tried that. But didn't work also. In this case, all I should do was to add this configuration to the end of the .xml file, right? Or should I replace the existing configuration?

Comment: @Kico: Replace.  Of course add back in any changed things like data sources.  But in general terms you can run OpenEJB with an xml file that contains only "<openejb/>", just you only would get defaults.

Comment: @David: when is 3.1.3 release scheduled?

Comment: @grigory: It's up for a vote http://markmail.org/message/drpsrrzeybrotr5n  Will probably close that vote and push it out today or tomorrow.